# How to set an accordion item expanded when load the page as default in nextjs?

Tags: next.js13, chakra-ui

I'm trying to set an Accordion Item expanded when the page is loaded (getting the id from the URL).
I'm trying to set it up (considering I'm working on a Next.js 13 App), through index or defaultIndex but without success.
Does someone has any clue?

Try using the default props described in the doc but not working.